# React js server side rendering window, document, jQuery and localStorage are not working

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, server-side-rendering, prerender

While rendering react application at server side window, document, jQuery and localStorage are not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use server side rendering in your application, the first renderer process is done by the server, not by the client (the browser). On the client, we can access to objects like window, document, localStorage, etc. because these all are the property of the browser. However, on the server these objects are not available yet.

I did this scheme a long time ago. It explains the process of renderer in a SSR App. In your case, objects like window will be available only from point 6 (the first green step). Every red step is a server process (here, the properties of the browser are not accesible)

[image]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Is there any alternate to use in my situation ?

Comment: I use the library 'mobile-detect' to know if the first request is done by a mobile phone, tablet or desktop. It uses javascript and it can use by the server. To handle data, I use the Redux store of the server and afterwards I provide all information to client in window.INITIAL_STATE object (in the body of HTML)(point 5)